# Cannot convert cURL request to RestTemplate

Tags: spring, proxy, httprequest, resttemplate

I want to make an HTTP Request from my server so I opened a tunnel in my port *8082*  as follows:

```
ssh -D 8082 jscherman@myserver
```

This way,  I can successfully do the following request from my local machine using *myserver* as a proxy:

```
madmin’s-MacBook-Pro:~ jscherman$ curl --proxy socks5://localhost:8082 -i 'http://192.168.255.142/infrastructure/query?pretty=true' --data-urlencode "db=telegraf" --data-urlencode "q=SHOW MEASUREMENTS"
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.12.2
Date: Thu, 04 Apr 2019 18:07:10 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Request-Id: 7762bc1a-5704-11e9-8718-000000000000
X-Influxdb-Build: OSS
X-Influxdb-Version: 1.6.4
X-Request-Id: 7762bc1a-5704-11e9-8718-000000000000

{"results":[...]}
```

The thing is, I can make this request work in my code. This is what I tried (I'm opened to another solution though)

```
        SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory();

        Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.SOCKS, new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 8082));
        requestFactory.setProxy(proxy);

        RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate(requestFactory);

        final String baseURl = "http://192.168.255.142:80/infrastructure/query?pretty=true";
        final String query = "SHOW MEASUREMENTS";

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);

        MultiValueMap<String, String> map= new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
        map.add("db", "telegraf");
        map.add("q", query);

        HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> entity = new HttpEntity<>(map, headers);

        ResponseEntity<LinkedHashMap> forEntity = template.exchange(baseURl, HttpMethod.GET, entity, LinkedHashMap.class);
```

Then I get the following exception:

```
2019-04-04 14:55:09.429 DEBUG 22965 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : GET request for "http://192.168.255.142:80/infrastructure/query?pretty=true" resulted in 400 (Bad Request); invoking error handler
org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 400 Bad Request
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:94)
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:79)
    at org.springframework.web.client.ResponseErrorHandler.handleError(ResponseErrorHandler.java:63)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:730)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:688)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:644)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:564)
    at com.myenterprise.myprojectbe.metric.resolver.RealPushCountMetricResolver.resolveMany(RealPushCountMetricResolver.java:87)
    at com.myenterprise.myprojectbe.metric.MetricConsumer.consumeLatestOfManyNodes(MetricConsumer.java:57)
    at com.myenterprise.myprojectbe.node.NodeController.lambda$getAllNodes$4(NodeController.java:96)
    at java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
    at com.myenterprise.myprojectbe.node.NodeController.getAllNodes(NodeController.java:94)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:891)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:866)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.AbstractRequestLoggingFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractRequestLoggingFilter.java:246)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:90)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:155)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:123)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:108)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:806)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Response code 400 indicates, that your proxy works correctly (this is response from server). But your HttpMethod should be POST if you are sending application/x-www-form-urlencoded:

```
    ResponseEntity<LinkedHashMap> forEntity = template.exchange(baseURl, HttpMethod.POST, entity, LinkedHashMap.class);
```